# Using Joint Distributions and conditional probabilities

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference

[image: 7 question exercise]

This exercise is particularly confusing me because I do not understand the distribution of 'X-Y' or how to calculate the probabilities

Answer (score 1):

$$\mathbb P\{X-Y<a\}=\iint_{\{(x,y)\mid x-y<\alpha \}}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\mathrm dx\mathrm dy.$$

Comment: Hi thanks! I am still confused as to how I would compute this probability because alpha isn't a set number so how do I integrate ?

Comment: Remark that $$\{(x,y)\in (0,1)\times (0,x)\mid x-y\leq \alpha  \}\\ =\{(x,y)\in [0,1]^2\mid x-\alpha\leq y\leq x \}$$ $$=[0,\alpha ]\times [0,x]\cup [\alpha ,1]\times [x-\alpha ,x]$$

Comment: So if im not mistaken the probability will equal 2 alpha as you integrate x over (0,1) and y over ( x-alpha, x)?

Comment: You are mistaken. You should read more carefully my previous comment.